# How to change two id css that are in two different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's what I'm looking for.

I'm using a carousel, that slides through 7 svg's icons. Each icon has an `id`.

I'm changing the css of the currently displayed icon with the following css:

```
.slick-current #icon-1 path {
  fill: rgb(252, 238, 33);
}
```

`.slick-current` is a class of the div, the `#icon-1` is an `svg` element inside that `div`.

As the carousel goes through, I have 7 css styles like the one above that targets the current icon and applies different colors. What I want to do at the same time is to target a different div with different icon and apply some css to it. For example:

If `slick-current` has an svg with `#icon-1` then I want to change `.slick-active` div that contains svg `#icon-3`. Is there any way to combine these two together ?

Carousel code:

```
        <div class="col-1 slider-cat-nav" id="slider_categories">
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="digital_icon" src="img/icons/icon-d.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="inspire_icon" src="img/icons/icon-tools.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="perform_icon" src="img/icons/icon-search.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="automate_icon" src="img/icons/icon-rocket.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="develop_icon" src="img/icons/icon-ab.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="design_icon" src="img/icons/icon-tools.svg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="plan_icon" src="img/icons/icon-rocket.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Slick.js code:

```
  $('.slider-cat-name').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: false,
fade: true,
asNavFor: '.slider-cat-nav',
speed: 1000,
});

$('.slider-cat-nav').slick({
slidesToShow: 5,
slidesToScroll: -1,
arrows: false,
asNavFor: '.slider-cat-name',
vertical: true,
//autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
speed: 1000,
draggable: false
});
```

The classes `.slick-current` and .`slick-active` and other classes are added to the divs by slick.js.

The output looks like this:

```
<div class="col-1 slider-cat-nav slick-initialized slick-slider slick-vertical" id="slider_categories">
  <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list" style="height: 520px;"><div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; height: 1768px; transform: translate3d(0px, -520px, 0px);">
    <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide10" style="width: 42px;">
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="digital_icon" src="img/icons/icon-d.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide11" style="width: 42px;">
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="inspire_icon" src="img/icons/icon-tools.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide12" style="width: 42px;">
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="perform_icon" src="img/icons/icon-search.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide13" style="width: 42px;">
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="automate_icon" src="img/icons/icon-rocket.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide14" style="width: 42px;">
        <img class="svg cat-icons-op" id="develop_icon" src="img/icons/icon-ab.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make a [mcve] and include HTML and relevant CSS and jQ

Answer (score 0):

If it was just for one dimension you might have some success with general `~` and adjacent `+` sibling selectors, but with children involved I don't think it's possible in pure CSS. If I got it right (HTML/JS example would help), the way these scenarios are dealt with is to set some flag on a parent element by a script and customize rules of the children according to it (which shouldn't be a problem considering you are using a carousel). For example when setting `data-active-element="icon-1"` attribute on the parent then a rule could be:

```
[data-active-element="icon-1"] .slick-active #icon-3 { whatever }
```

Not very elegant but working.

For the JavaScript part, in your case [see the doc of the Slick library](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started), "events" section; haven't tested it but setting the parent's attribute might go somewhat like this:

```
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  nextSlide.parent().attr('data-active-element', nextSlide.attr('id'));
});
```

**Reference**
[General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors),
[Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)